# Combining a format string with a superscript and a subscript in pyplot when rendering text in a plot

Tags: matplotlib, format

I would like to include the equation for a "power-law" curve I am creating using pyplot.  I have tried several variations of the following code:

```
ax.text(0.1,0.9,r'{0:}x$^{1:}$'.format(A,b))
```

of course the text renderer uses the curly brackets as well as the format statement.  I have tried doubling the curly brackets to have

```
ax.text(0.1,0.9,r'{0:}x$^{{1:}}$'.format(A,b))
```

and even tripling them

```
ax.text(0.1,0.9,r'{0:}x$^{{{1:}}}$'.format(A,b))
```

I have also tried splitting the text into two lines

```
exponent = '{0:}$'.format(b)
ax.text(0.1,0.9,r'{0:}x$^'.format(A)+exponent)
```

none of these really make sense to me or to pyplot, but I can't seem to ask the right search question to get this to work.  I have found answers that suggested splitting the line and using double curly brackets but nothing that will make this work.  Is this possible?

EDIT:

Through further experimentation I have answered the question above which was a simplified version of the equation I wanted to put in the plot, so let me change this question slightly.  To do what I wanted above I have found that:

```
ax.text(0.1,0.9,r'{0:}x$^{{ {1:} }}$'.format(A,b))
```

works.  I don't know why I hadn't tried it earlier, but I have now.  The problem is that I actually want a subscript on x as well.  Given that the above works I would have thought that:

```
ax.text(0.1,0.9,r'{0:}x$^{{ {1:} }}_{{\rm map}}$
```

would work, but I get the following error:

> Subscript/superscript sequence is too long.  Use braces { } to remove
>   ambiguity. (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)

I cannot see where to add braces that will remove any ambiguity.  Can anyone tell me what I need to do?

Comment: Your last line of code is incomplete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
ax.text(0.1, 0.9, r'${0:}x^{{{1:}}}_{{\rm map}}$'.format(A, b))
```

The issue was that your `x` was outside of the mathmode (`$...$`).

With regards to the double curly braces, there is an easy explanation: When using the format function all single curly braces are matched with an argument to the format function (they can also be nested). Two subsequent curly braces are *the* defined way of getting one curly bracket after applying format. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) for more information on this.

Comment: This is interesting, I often keep the variable outside the $$ in order to avoid the need for the \rm, so it didn't occur to me to try that.  Apparently it is necessary in this case!